# MSBuild $(version)?

Tags: msbuild

In our target `DestinationFiles` we wish to set path to contain the version number of the project file we use to build. Is there a variable we can use to get that value?

```
< Target Name="CopyOutput">
  <ItemGroup>
     <PackagedFiles Include="blah blah"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" 
        DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'\\Blah\SOME_VERSION_NUMBER_FROM_BUILD\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342620/generating-version-number-in-msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

Sure just use `$(VARNAME)` and call msbuild with `/p:VARNAME=XXXX`

For more details regarding using enviornment vars with msbuild, you can have a look at https://sbarnea.com/articles/easy-windows-build-versioning/