# assembly version generation in git for a Visual studio Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and git for version control for a .Net solution. I'm using an Installshield setup project. I need the Solution's assembly version number to increment so that previous installs are removed when new versions are installed.  Is there a way to get some kind of incremental numbering from git with every commit that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work reliably for builds in feature branches, but for release builds from `master` you could do something like `git rev-list master --count --first-parent` to give you a new "version" for every new commit (not counting those merged in). More often, though, you would use an auto-incrementing build number from a CI server (TFS, TeamCity, etc).

As for actually applying this version number to your assembly, there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517135/54249) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342620/generating-version-number-in-msbuild).

Comment: Thanks. I think that `git rev-list master --count --first-parent` meets my needs.